# Does the order of dependencies matter in the visual studio compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a vc++ project with about 8 dependencies. The compiler complains some references are not found, but i have double checked and the **static library** is linked to the project.

The type of project i am trying to compile is the **Dynamic library** Project.

In visual studio project settings, does the order of the linker dependencies matter for compilation.

Comment: Pretty hard to make sense of "The compiler complains some references are not found".  You certainly can have build order problems and cause linker errors.  So set the build dependencies explicitly.